# A results page with multiple shares/likes

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

My question is simple yet I do not know how to solve it without cache and I would like to query if there is another solution.

I have a not-for-profit website for pairing between elderly people and housing solutions.

The site is listed as an app and has an app Id but users are not required to log in to view information (I want this to be as friendly as possible for elderly people).

The problem is caused by a specific page in my sites that shows all housing solutions (each of them has also a detailed page of its own):
https://compair.biz/SearchResults/Results…

In the results page I use a graph api call to show the number of likes/shares per each result (from its individual page---all pages are within my domain).
The problem is that I hit the rate limits every time since I make too many calls (one user and more than 200 calls).

Is there another type of call or another solution to show the likes/shares without heating the rate limit?

More details below:

html:

```
<input class="likes1" type="hidden" id="institueId_@Model.InstituteId" 
value="@Model.InstituteId" data-link="" />
<div class="likes2" id=@resultsId style="padding-top:5px;color:#1D7872"> 
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function countFacebookLikes() {
$('.likes2').each(function () {
var $currentForm = $(this).closest('.DetailedInfoForm');
var token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY', //this is an 
//access token from facebook

resultsId = $('.likes1', $currentForm).val(),
urlName = 'https://compair.biz/DetailedInfo/Result?id=' + resultsId;

$.ajax({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1',
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
data: { access_token: token, id: urlName },
success: function (data) {
if (data != undefined && data.share != undefined) {
$('#results' + resultsId).html('<a 
href="https://compair.biz/DetailedInfo/Result?id=' + resultsId + '" 
class="BtnImageToDetailedInfo"><span class="badge badge-roundless badge- 
likes inline-block">' + data.share.share_count + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<i 
class="fa fa-thumbs-up">' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<i class="fa fa-facebook- 
square" >' + '</span></a>');
$('#popular' + resultsId).html(data.share.share_count);
}
else {
$('#popular' + resultsId).html(0);
}
}
});
};
```

Comment: First of all, app or page access tokens should never be exposed in client-side code, where everyone could steal them. You just exposed your app access token here, so you need to go reset your app secret _now_, if you don’t want everyone here to be able to use it to perform operations in the name of your app.

Comment: You should move this over to the server side, and implement some form of caching, so that you don’t hit the API on every single page visit. Or you just use the Like/Share button social plugin, that can show the current counter without costing you any API calls.

Comment: Thanks @misorude for both comments. How can I show in a results page (whith its own dedicated url) the Like/Share button social plugin that shows the current counter of  other urls? (the results)

Comment: You just need to point the href/data-href attribute of each like button to the proper target URL.

Comment: This works @misorude. A bit slow, obviously, when there are many results, but fine nevertheless. Thanks